# Rest assured with digest auth

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-security, rest-assured

I have a working spring-mvc application with rest services and some rest-assured tests which are fine :

```
@Test
public void createFoobarFromScratchReturns201(){
    expect().statusCode(201).given()    
    .queryParam("foo", generateFoo())
    .queryParam("bar", generateBar())
    .when().post("/foo/bar/");
}

=> OK
```

Then I implemented a **digest** authentication. Everything is working well, now I have to log in to use my services :

```
curl http://localhost:8089/foo/bar
=> HTTP ERROR 401,  Full authentication is required to access this resource

curl http://localhost:8089/foo/bar --digest -u user_test:password
=> HTTP 201, CREATED
```

But when I try to upgrade my tests with the [most obvious function](https://rest-assured.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/apidocs/com/jayway/restassured/RestAssured.html#digest(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), I still have a 401 error :

```
@Test
public void createFoobarFromScratchReturns201(){
    expect().statusCode(201).given()    
    .auth().digest("user_test", "password") // Digest added here
    .queryParam("foo", generateFoo())
    .queryParam("bar", generateBar())
    .when().post("/foo/bar/");
}

=> Expected status code <201> doesn't match actual status code <401>
```

I found some clues with the **preemptive()** function, but it seems to be only implemented for basic :

```
// Returns an AuthenticatedScheme and stores it into the general configuration
RestAssured.authentication = preemptive().basic("user_test", "password");

// Try a similar thing, but it didn't work :
RestAssured.authentication = RestAssured.digest("user_test", "password");
```

Currently, I am trying to achieve two things :

- I need to upgrade a couple of my tests to support digest
- I need to amend the *@Before* of the rest of my tests suites (whose are not related to auth issues), to be already logged in.

Any ideas or documentation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try enabling support for cookies in the HTTP client embedded inside Rest Assured with:

```
 RestAssuredConfig config = new RestAssuredConfig().httpClient(new HttpClientConfig().setParam(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY, CookiePolicy.BEST_MATCH));

 expect().statusCode(201).given()    
 .auth().digest("user_test", "password") // Digest added here
 .config(config)
 .queryParam("foo", generateFoo())
 .queryParam("bar", generateBar())
 .when().post("/foo/bar/");
```

The HTTP client (and therefore Rest Assured) supports digest authentication and the configuration of RestAssured using the `digest` method works well.

Comment: It doesn't change much, I still have "Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 401 Incorrect response" and "DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << HTTP/1.1 401 Incorrect response"

Comment: Then I'm quite out of ideas, it helped when I faced the same problem. As you have control over the server you're authenticating to, in your place I'd try to troubleshoot on that side by inspecting what's actually coming from the RestAssured and comparing to the input from curl - perhaps it's some encoding problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway, I compared the two requests and the only differences are the headers : nonce and response. So that's means that the message is not correctly hashed.

Comment: I was on the same track and ended up making HTTP client's code calculate hashes for the values I knew the correct result for. And it turned out that HTTP client was getting the values right. Which doesn't mean that there can't be a bug on either side which you're hitting. If you send me username + realm + password + nonce + cnonce I can run in through HTTP client again and see if we get the same result.

Comment: Thanks, I will do it on Monday

Comment: I'm the founder if REST Assured and if there's anything that can be done from my side to improve this then please let me know.